# Android Error : Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, view

I read other posts but didnt solved my problem. I am newbie on Android. I have to connect to MSSQL but i am getting the original thread error. How can i solve this? Thanks.

Here is my code :

```
private class MyThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {

        durumKontrol();
        if (isConnected) {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    kuyrukKontrol();
                }

            }).start();

        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast
                    .makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Ağa erişilemiyor. Lütfen kablosuz ağın açık olduğundan emin olunuz",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }

        tick_Handler.postDelayed(tick_thread, firstDelay);
        firstDelay = 10000;
    }

}private void kuyrukKontrol() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Hücrenin sipariş ettiği ve henüz getirilmemiş malzemelerin listesi
    // çekiliyor
    TextView tvIP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIP);
    tvIP.setText(HatAdi + "-" + HucreNo);


    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433",
                        "xx", "xxxxx");

        Statement query = conn.createStatement();

        // İlk olarak bu forklifte ait teslim edilmeyen bir talep var mı
        ResultSet rs = query
                .executeQuery("select * from MOBILE.dbo.fos_SS where hucreNo = '" + HucreNo + "' and sonDurum != 'T'");
        while (rs.next()) {

            KuyrugaEkle(rs.getString("malzemeNo"),rs.getString("sonDurum"),rs.getString("sonIslemZamani"));

        }

        rs.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and in KuyrugaEkle function i dynamically change the layout, and i am getting error in that function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to modify the UI from thread other than main, and you do that in the function `kuyrukKontrol`. Use `Handler` or `runOnUiThread` to perform it on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Object of the MyThread and use it in runOnUiThread method

```
MyThread mt = new MyThread();
```

Get the Activity's context and use the following code

```
Activity a=(Activity)context;
            a.runOnUiThread(mt);
```

Pass the Applications context to the MyThread class's constructor and use it as I mentioned above.

Comment: You can't necessarily cast the getApplicationContext to an Activity, right?

Comment: @DavidDoria : It's actually activity's context I have edited it :)